# Folder structure from a string that has a parent child relationship

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I have a scenario where I get a string output from a service that returns a folder structure as below

```
id=0c06c81c8052324b;name=Documentation;type=root;|id=0b06c81c80524a87;name=ABC;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8052324b;|id=0b06c81c80524837;name=Admin;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052483d;name=Admin 2.0;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524837;|id=0b06c81c8052483a;name=Panel;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052484a;name=VCM;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8052483a;|id=0c06c81c80269e63;name=Invoices;type=root;|id=0b06c81c8026a008;name=other;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c80269e63;|id=0b06c81c8027a600;name=Workflow;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8026a008;|id=0b06c81c8027a601;name=Worksheet;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8027a600;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d3;name=Receipts;type=root;|id=0b06c81c80545f32;name=VR_2;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f33;name=VR_3;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f30;name=VR_1;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c8053486d;name=VR;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f31;name=test2;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8053486d;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d2;name=Source;type=root;|id=0b06c81c80524a8b;name=gem;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d2;|id=0b06c81c80521681;name=Code;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;|id=0b06c81c8051cba7;name=pfm;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;
```

I was able to write a recursive logic to parse that string to come up with a structure as below:

```
Children of DCMGEN -> Documentation, ID: 0c06c81c8052324b
Children of DCMGEN -> Invoices, ID: 0c06c81c80269e63
Children of DCMGEN -> Source, ID: 0c06c81c8051c7d2
Children of DCMGEN -> Receipts, ID: 0c06c81c8051c7d3
Children of Documentation -> ABC, ID: 0b06c81c80524a87
Children of ABC -> Admin, ID: 0b06c81c80524837
Children of ABC -> Panel, ID: 0b06c81c8052483a
Children of Admin -> Admin 2.0, ID: 0b06c81c8052483d
Children of Panel -> VCM, ID: 0b06c81c8052484a
Children of Invoices -> other, ID: 0b06c81c8026a008
Children of other -> Workflow, ID: 0b06c81c8027a600
Children of Workflow -> Worksheet, ID: 0b06c81c8027a601
Children of Source -> gem, ID: 0b06c81c80524a8b
Children of gem -> Code, ID: 0b06c81c80521681
Children of gem -> pfm, ID: 0b06c81c8051cba7
Children of Receipts -> VR_2, ID: 0b06c81c80545f32
Children of Receipts -> VR_3, ID: 0b06c81c80545f33
Children of Receipts -> VR_1, ID: 0b06c81c80545f30
Children of Receipts -> VR, ID: 0b06c81c8053486d
Children of VR -> test2, ID: 0b06c81c80545f31
```

However, I want to create a folder structure from it on my local machine but am not able to create it recursively. Looking for some clues to solve this recursive problem. Can anyone please help ??

```
DCMGEN
    Documentation
        ABC
            Admin
                Admin 2.0
            Panel
                VCM
    Invoices
        other
            Workflow
                Worksheet

    Source
        gem
            Code
            pfm

    Receipts
        VR
            test2
        VR_1
        VR_2
        VR_3
```

Below is my code to get this far (with the help of some other [thread on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570146/convert-java-arraylist-of-parent-child-relation-into-tree)):

**MegaMenuDTO.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MegaMenuDTO {

    private String Id;
    private String name;
    private String parentId;
    private String type;
    private List<MegaMenuDTO> childrenItems; 

    public MegaMenuDTO() {
        this.Id = "";
        this.name = "";     
        this.parentId = "";
        this.childrenItems = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        Id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }
    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }
    public List<MegaMenuDTO> getChildrenItems() {
        return childrenItems;
    }
    public void setChildrenItems(List<MegaMenuDTO> childrenItems) {
        this.childrenItems = childrenItems;
    }
    public void addChildrenItem(MegaMenuDTO childrenItem){
        if(!this.childrenItems.contains(childrenItem))
            this.childrenItems.add(childrenItem);
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
//        return "MegaMenuDTO [Id=" + Id + ", name=" + name + ", parentId="
//                + parentId + ", childrenItems=" + childrenItems + "]";
        return "[name=" + name + ", childrenItems=" + childrenItems + "]";
    }

}
```

**MenuHelper.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MenuHelper {
    private static final String TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER = "DCMGEN";
    private static final String JAVA_IO_TMPDIR = "java.io.tmpdir";
    private static final String FOLDERTREE_STR = "foldertree=";
    private static final String RECORD_ELEMENT_DELIM = "[\\|]+";
    private static final String SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    private static Map<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>> parentChildMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>>();
    private static Map<String, String> idNameMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    //Test this helper class....
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String FOLDER_STRUCTURE = "id=0c06c81c8052324b;name=Documentation;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c80524a87;name=ABC;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8052324b;|id=0b06c81c80524837;name=Admin;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052483d;name=Admin 2.0;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524837;|id=0b06c81c8052483a;name=Panel;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052484a;name=VCM;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8052483a;|id=0c06c81c80269e63;name=Invoices;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c8026a008;name=other;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c80269e63;|id=0b06c81c8027a600;name=Workflow;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8026a008;|id=0b06c81c8027a601;name=Worksheet;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8027a600;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d3;name=Receipts;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c80545f32;name=VR_2;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f33;name=VR_3;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f30;name=VR_1;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c8053486d;name=VR;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f31;name=test2;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8053486d;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d2;name=Source;type=root;|id=0b06c81c80524a8b;name=gem;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d2;|id=0b06c81c80521681;name=Code;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;|id=0b06c81c8051cba7;name=pfm;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;";

        System.out.println("Temp folder : " + System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR));

        List<FolderObj> folders = MenuHelper.parseResponseString(FOLDER_STRUCTURE);
        if(folders != null) {
            List<MegaMenuDTO> menuDTOList = MenuHelper.prepareMenu(folders);
            List<File> rootDirs = new ArrayList<>();
            File rootDir = new File(System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR) + SEPARATOR + TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER);
            //Check and Delete the root folder, if present, before processing.
            if(rootDir.exists()) {
                rootDirs.add(rootDir);
                for(File file : rootDirs) {
                    recursivelyDelete(file);
                }
            }

            //Create a fresh root dir.
            rootDirs.clear();
            rootDir = createTempRootDir(TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER);
            rootDirs.add(rootDir);

            //System.out.println("Tree : " + menuDTOList);
            for(MegaMenuDTO mmd: menuDTOList){
                printMenu(mmd, "\t");
                captureIdNameMap(mmd);
                printPaths(mmd, TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER + SEPARATOR + mmd.getName());
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>> entry : parentChildMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<MegaMenuDTO> value = entry.getValue();
                for(MegaMenuDTO dto : value) {
                    if(idNameMap.get(key) == null) {
                        System.out.println("Children of " + key + " -> " + dto.getName() + ", ID: " + dto.getId());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Children of " + idNameMap.get(key) + " -> " + dto.getName() + ", ID: " + dto.getId());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<FolderObj> parseResponseString(final String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<FolderObj> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] parsedValues = input.split(RECORD_ELEMENT_DELIM);
        for(short i=0; i < parsedValues.length; i++) {
            menuList.add(digest(filterValue(parsedValues[i])));
        }
        return menuList;
    }

    public static String filterValue(String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return input;
        }

        if(input.contains(FOLDERTREE_STR)) {
            input = input.substring(input.indexOf(FOLDERTREE_STR) + FOLDERTREE_STR.length());
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static FolderObj digest(String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
        String [] keyVals = input.split(";");
        for(String keyVal : keyVals) {
            String [] parts = keyVal.split("=");
            holder.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

        FolderObj folderObj = null;
        String childId = null;
        String name = null;
        String type = null;
        String parentId = null;

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();

            if(key.equals("id")) {
                childId = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("name")) {
                name = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("type")) {
                type = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("parent")) {
                parentId = entry.getValue();
            } 

            folderObj = new FolderObj(childId, parentId, name, type);
        }
        return folderObj;
    }

    public static List<MegaMenuDTO> prepareMenu(List<FolderObj> folderList) {
        // Arrange String corresponds to the Id
        Map<String, MegaMenuDTO> megaMenuMap = new HashMap<>();

        // populate a Map
        for(FolderObj folderObj: folderList){

            //  ----- Child -----
            MegaMenuDTO mmdChild;
            if(megaMenuMap.containsKey(folderObj.getChildId())){
                mmdChild = megaMenuMap.get(folderObj.getChildId());
            }
            else{
                mmdChild = new MegaMenuDTO();
                megaMenuMap.put(folderObj.getChildId(),mmdChild);
            }           
            mmdChild.setId(folderObj.getChildId());
            mmdChild.setParentId(folderObj.getParentId());
            mmdChild.setName(folderObj.getName());
            mmdChild.setType(folderObj.getType());
            // no need to set ChildrenItems list because the constructor created a new empty list

            // ------ Parent ----
            MegaMenuDTO mmdParent;
            if(megaMenuMap.containsKey(folderObj.getParentId())){
                mmdParent = megaMenuMap.get(folderObj.getParentId());
            }
            else{
                mmdParent = new MegaMenuDTO();
                megaMenuMap.put(folderObj.getParentId(),mmdParent);
            }
            mmdParent.setId(folderObj.getParentId());
//            mmdParent.setParentId(null);         
            mmdParent.addChildrenItem(mmdChild);
        }

        // Get the root
        List<MegaMenuDTO> menuList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>(); 
        for(MegaMenuDTO megaMenuDTO : megaMenuMap.values()){
            if(megaMenuDTO.getParentId() == null)
                menuList.add(megaMenuDTO);
        }
        return menuList;
    }

    private static void printMenu(MegaMenuDTO dto, String tabValue) {
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            System.out.println(tabValue + childDTO.getName());
            tabValue = "\t" + tabValue;
            printMenu(childDTO, tabValue);
        }
    }

    private static void captureIdNameMap(MegaMenuDTO dto) throws IOException {
        idNameMap.put(dto.getId(), dto.getName());
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            idNameMap.put(childDTO.getId(), childDTO.getName());
            captureIdNameMap(childDTO);
        }
    }
    private static void printPaths(MegaMenuDTO dto, String name) throws IOException {
        if(dto.getParentId() == null) {
            if(parentChildMap.get("ROOT") == null) {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>();
                parentList.add(dto);
                parentChildMap.put("ROOT", parentList);
            } else {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = parentChildMap.get("ROOT");
                parentList.add(dto);
                parentChildMap.put("ROOT", parentList);
            }
        }
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            if (parentChildMap.get(childDTO.getParentId()) == null) {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>();
                parentList.add(childDTO);
                parentChildMap.put(childDTO.getParentId(), parentList);
            } else {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = parentChildMap.get(childDTO.getParentId());
                parentList.add(childDTO);
                parentChildMap.put(childDTO.getParentId(), parentList);
            }
            System.out.println(name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName() + ", ParentId : " + childDTO.getParentId());
            createTempRootDir(name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName());  
            name = name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName();
            printPaths(childDTO, name);
        }
    }

    public static File createTempRootDir(String name) throws IOException {
        final File sysTempDir = new File(System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR));
        File newTempDir = new File(sysTempDir, name);
        if (newTempDir.mkdirs()) {
            return newTempDir;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Failed to create temp dir named " + newTempDir.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively delete file or directory
     * 
     * @param fileOrDir
     *            the file or dir to delete
     * @return true iff all files are successfully deleted
     */
    public static void recursivelyDelete(File fileOrDir) throws IOException {
        Path directory = Paths.get(fileOrDir.getAbsolutePath());
        Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
           @Override
           public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
               Files.delete(file);
               return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
           }

           @Override
           public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
               Files.delete(dir);
               return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code. Part of the pre-work one should do before posting on SO is reducing the amount of code to show to the bear minimum. Could you please narrow your problem down to the essential ?

Comment: Also, I have to ask: are you doing this for learning about recursivity or because you're not aware such functions are already implemented in the standard library or popular Java common utils ?

Comment: I tried to paste the entire code as people in the past have asked for it in several iterations.

Comment: I am not trying to learn recursivity but rather trying to solve this problem that I have. I have done a lot of trials before approaching this forum. Dont want to be downvoted for not giving a shot at it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work after reading up more on recursion. Below is the new updated code for anyone trying to do something similar. Not claiming that this is the most efficient or shortest code possible but the best I could come up with. If someone has an improved version, I would be very happy to see that.

**MenuHelper.java**

```
public class MenuHelper {
    private static final String TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER = "DCMGEN";
    private static final String JAVA_IO_TMPDIR = "java.io.tmpdir";
    private static final String FOLDERTREE_STR = "foldertree=";
    private static final String RECORD_ELEMENT_DELIM = "[\\|]+";
    private static final String SEPARATOR = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    private static Map<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>> parentChildMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>>();
    private static Map<String, String> idNameMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    //Test this helper class....
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String FOLDER_STRUCTURE = "id=0c06c81c8052324b;name=Documentation;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c80524a87;name=ABC;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8052324b;|id=0b06c81c80524837;name=Admin;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052483d;name=Admin 2.0;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524837;|id=0b06c81c8052483a;name=Panel;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a87;|id=0b06c81c8052484a;name=VCM;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8052483a;|id=0c06c81c80269e63;name=Invoices;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c8026a008;name=other;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c80269e63;|id=0b06c81c8027a600;name=Workflow;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8026a008;|id=0b06c81c8027a601;name=Worksheet;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8027a600;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d3;name=Receipts;type=cabinet;|id=0b06c81c80545f32;name=VR_2;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f33;name=VR_3;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f30;name=VR_1;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c8053486d;name=VR;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d3;|id=0b06c81c80545f31;name=test2;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c8053486d;|id=0c06c81c8051c7d2;name=Source;type=root;|id=0b06c81c80524a8b;name=gem;type=folder;parent=0c06c81c8051c7d2;|id=0b06c81c80521681;name=Code;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;|id=0b06c81c8051cba7;name=pfm;type=folder;parent=0b06c81c80524a8b;";

        System.out.println("Temp folder : " + System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR));

        List<FolderObj> folders = MenuHelper.parseResponseString(FOLDER_STRUCTURE);
        if(folders != null) {
            List<MegaMenuDTO> menuDTOList = MenuHelper.prepareMenu(folders);
            List<File> rootDirs = new ArrayList<>();
            File rootDir = new File(System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR) + SEPARATOR + TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER);
            //Check and Delete the root folder, if present, before processing.
            if(rootDir.exists()) {
                rootDirs.add(rootDir);
                for(File file : rootDirs) {
                    recursivelyDelete(file);
                }
            }

            //Create a fresh root dir.
            rootDirs.clear();
            rootDir = createTempRootDir(TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER);
            rootDirs.add(rootDir);

            //System.out.println("Tree : " + menuDTOList);
            for(MegaMenuDTO mmd: menuDTOList){
                printMenu(mmd, "\t");
                captureIdNameMap(mmd);
                printPaths(mmd, TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER + SEPARATOR + mmd.getName());
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>> entry : parentChildMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<MegaMenuDTO> value = entry.getValue();
                for(MegaMenuDTO dto : value) {
                    if(idNameMap.get(key) == null) {
                        System.out.println("Children of " + key + " -> " + dto.getName() + ", ID: " + dto.getId());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Children of " + idNameMap.get(key) + " -> " + dto.getName() + ", ID: " + dto.getId());
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("--------------------------------------\n");
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<MegaMenuDTO>> entry : parentChildMap.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                List<MegaMenuDTO> value = entry.getValue();
                if(key.equals("ROOT")) {
                    for(MegaMenuDTO dto : value) {
                        System.out.println("Root Folder is : " + dto.getName());
                        //createTempRootDir(TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER + SEPARATOR + dto.getName());
                        System.out.println(TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER + SEPARATOR + dto.getName());
                        printFoldersRecursively(parentChildMap.get(dto.getId()), TEMP_ROOT_FOLDER + SEPARATOR + dto.getName());                             
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printFoldersRecursively(List<MegaMenuDTO> value, String rootPath) throws IOException {
         for (MegaMenuDTO inDTO1 : value) {
             System.out.println(rootPath + SEPARATOR + inDTO1.getName());
             for(MegaMenuDTO childItem : inDTO1.getChildrenItems()) {
                 System.out.println(rootPath + SEPARATOR + inDTO1.getName() + SEPARATOR + childItem.getName());
                 printFoldersRecursively(childItem.getChildrenItems(), rootPath + SEPARATOR + inDTO1.getName() + SEPARATOR + childItem.getName());
             }
         }
    }

    public static List<FolderObj> parseResponseString(final String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<FolderObj> menuList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] parsedValues = input.split(RECORD_ELEMENT_DELIM);
        for(short i=0; i < parsedValues.length; i++) {
            menuList.add(digest(filterValue(parsedValues[i])));
        }
        return menuList;
    }

    public static String filterValue(String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return input;
        }

        if(input.contains(FOLDERTREE_STR)) {
            input = input.substring(input.indexOf(FOLDERTREE_STR) + FOLDERTREE_STR.length());
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static FolderObj digest(String input) {
        if(input == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, String> holder = new HashMap<>();
        String [] keyVals = input.split(";");
        for(String keyVal : keyVals) {
            String [] parts = keyVal.split("=");
            holder.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

        FolderObj folderObj = null;
        String childId = null;
        String name = null;
        String type = null;
        String parentId = null;

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : holder.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();

            if(key.equals("id")) {
                childId = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("name")) {
                name = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("type")) {
                type = entry.getValue();
            } else if(key.equals("parent")) {
                parentId = entry.getValue();
            } 

            folderObj = new FolderObj(childId, parentId, name, type);
        }
        return folderObj;
    }

    public static List<MegaMenuDTO> prepareMenu(List<FolderObj> folderList) {
        // Arrange String corresponds to the Id
        Map<String, MegaMenuDTO> megaMenuMap = new HashMap<>();

        // populate a Map
        for(FolderObj folderObj: folderList){
            MegaMenuDTO mmdChild;
            if(megaMenuMap.containsKey(folderObj.getChildId())){
                mmdChild = megaMenuMap.get(folderObj.getChildId());
            } else{
                mmdChild = new MegaMenuDTO();
                megaMenuMap.put(folderObj.getChildId(),mmdChild);
            }           
            mmdChild.setId(folderObj.getChildId());
            mmdChild.setParentId(folderObj.getParentId());
            mmdChild.setName(folderObj.getName());
            mmdChild.setType(folderObj.getType());

            // ------ Parent ----
            MegaMenuDTO mmdParent;
            if(megaMenuMap.containsKey(folderObj.getParentId())){
                mmdParent = megaMenuMap.get(folderObj.getParentId());
            } else{
                mmdParent = new MegaMenuDTO();
                megaMenuMap.put(folderObj.getParentId(),mmdParent);
            }
            mmdParent.setId(folderObj.getParentId());
            mmdParent.addChildrenItem(mmdChild);
        }

        // Get the root
        List<MegaMenuDTO> menuList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>(); 
        for(MegaMenuDTO megaMenuDTO : megaMenuMap.values()){
            if(megaMenuDTO.getParentId() == null)
                menuList.add(megaMenuDTO);
        }
        return menuList;
    }

    private static void printMenu(MegaMenuDTO dto, String tabValue) {
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            System.out.println(tabValue + childDTO.getName());
            tabValue = "\t" + tabValue;
            printMenu(childDTO, tabValue);
        }
    }

    private static void captureIdNameMap(MegaMenuDTO dto) throws IOException {
        idNameMap.put(dto.getId(), dto.getName());
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            idNameMap.put(childDTO.getId(), childDTO.getName());
            captureIdNameMap(childDTO);
        }
    }
    private static void printPaths(MegaMenuDTO dto, String name) throws IOException {
        if(dto.getParentId() == null) {
            if(parentChildMap.get("ROOT") == null) {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>();
                parentList.add(dto);
                parentChildMap.put("ROOT", parentList);
            } else {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = parentChildMap.get("ROOT");
                parentList.add(dto);
                parentChildMap.put("ROOT", parentList);
            }
        }
        for(MegaMenuDTO childDTO : dto.getChildrenItems()) {
            if (parentChildMap.get(childDTO.getParentId()) == null) {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = new ArrayList<MegaMenuDTO>();
                parentList.add(childDTO);
                parentChildMap.put(childDTO.getParentId(), parentList);
            } else {
                List<MegaMenuDTO> parentList = parentChildMap.get(childDTO.getParentId());
                parentList.add(childDTO);
                parentChildMap.put(childDTO.getParentId(), parentList);
            }
            System.out.println(name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName() + ", ParentId : " + childDTO.getParentId());
            createTempRootDir(name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName());  
            name = name + SEPARATOR + childDTO.getName();
            printPaths(childDTO, name);
        }
    }

    public static File createTempRootDir(String name) throws IOException {
        final File sysTempDir = new File(System.getProperty(JAVA_IO_TMPDIR));
        File newTempDir = new File(sysTempDir, name);
        if (newTempDir.mkdirs()) {
            return newTempDir;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Failed to create temp dir named " + newTempDir.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recursively delete file or directory
     * 
     * @param fileOrDir
     *            the file or dir to delete
     * @return true iff all files are successfully deleted
     */
    public static void recursivelyDelete(File fileOrDir) throws IOException {
        Path directory = Paths.get(fileOrDir.getAbsolutePath());
        Files.walkFileTree(directory, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
           @Override
           public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
               Files.delete(file);
               return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
           }

           @Override
           public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
               Files.delete(dir);
               return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
           }
        });
    }
}
```